# Get the dates of the last month and sum it by day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the dates of the last month and sum it by day?

I use "CAST" to convert the date to YY.MM.DD. And "COUNT" to count the number of defects (they are stored as strings)

My code:

```
SELECT
    CAST([MyDate] AS DATE),
    COUNT(MyDefects)
FROM
    MyDataBase
WHERE
    [MyDate] is not null
GROUP BY
    [MyDate]
ORDER BY
    [MyDate] ASC
```

Part of my output:

```
2020-02-06  1
2020-02-06  1
2020-02-06  1
2020-02-06  1
2020-02-06  1
2020-02-06  1
2020-02-06  27
2020-02-05  1
2020-02-05  1
2020-02-05  1
2020-02-05  1
2020-02-05  1
2020-02-05  1
2020-02-05  1
2020-02-05  1
2020-02-05  1
2020-02-05  1
2020-02-05  1
```

Comment: Look at `DATEPART()` and group by day, month and year. It's grim storing dates as strings though, probs want to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CAST([MyDate] AS DATE),
    COUNT(MyDefects)
FROM
    MyDataBase
WHERE
    [MyDate] is not null and MONTH([MyDate]) = MONTH(getdate()) - 1
GROUP BY
    CAST([MyDate] AS DATE)
ORDER BY
    CAST([MyDate] AS DATE) ASC
```

Comment: This isn't summing by day.